# Evaluate $\int \frac{xe^x}{1+x^2}dx$

Tags: integration

> Evaluate $\int \frac{xe^x}{1+x^2}dx$

**My attempt:** I tried to evaluate the integral by parts considering $\frac{x}{1+x^2}$ as first function and $e^x$ as second function but did not get anything useful.

Comment: You may have to represent the result in terms of $\mathrm{Ei}(x)$ i.e. Exponential integral.

Comment: If you are familiar with Complex Analysis, then you can express your integrand as $\frac{z\cdot e^z}{1+z^2}=\frac{z\cdot e^z}{(1+iz)(1-iz)}$. This is easily solved by using Residue Theory. E.g. check E. Stein, R. Shakarchi "Complex Analysis".

Comment: This is equivalent to solving the differential equation $$ g(x)+g'(x)=\frac{x}{x^2+1}.$$ The non-elementary exponential integral cannot be avoided since the RHS has simple poles at $x=\pm i$.

Comment: You can perform partial fraction decomposition, and then use the $Ei(x)$.

Comment: Was the original question a definite integral?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\int\frac{x\mathrm{e}^x}{x^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}x&=\int\frac{x\mathrm{e}^x}{\left(x-i\right)\left(x+i\right)}\,\mathrm{d}x \\ & = \int\left(\frac{\mathrm{e}^x}{2\left(x+i\right)}+\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^x}{2\left(x-i\right)}\right)\mathrm{d}x \\ &= \frac{1}{2}\underbrace{\int\frac{\mathrm{e}^x}{x+i}\,\mathrm{d}x}_{\equiv I_1}+\frac{1}{2}\underbrace{\int\frac{\mathrm{e}^x}{x-i}\,\mathrm{d}x}_{\equiv I_2}
\end{align}

To evaluate $I_1$ make $u=x+i$. This change of variable give us

$$I_1=\mathrm{e}^{-i}\int\frac{\mathrm{e}^u}{u}\,\mathrm{d}u=\mathrm{e}^{-i}\operatorname{Ei}\left(x+i\right),$$

since

$$ \int\frac{\mathrm{e}^u}{u}\,\mathrm{d}u=\operatorname{Ei}\left(u\right), $$

where $\operatorname{Ei}$ is the [Exponential integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialIntegral.html). A similar approach with $u=x-i$ gives

$$I_2=\mathrm{e}^{i}\int\frac{\mathrm{e}^u}{u}\,\mathrm{d}u=\mathrm{e}^{i}\operatorname{Ei}\left(x-i\right).$$

Thereby,

$$ \int\frac{x\mathrm{e}^x}{x^2+1}=\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-i}\operatorname{Ei}\left(x+i\right)+\mathrm{e}^i\operatorname{Ei}\left(x-i\right)}{2}+C.$$